# Font "Shantell Sans" not being downloaded

Tags: android, fonts, google-fonts, android-downloadable-fonts

I am trying to use [this font from Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Shantell+Sans) for my Android app. I want it as a [downloadable font](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/text-and-emoji/downloadable-fonts).

So, I have on res/fonts folder this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:fontProviderAuthority="com.google.android.gms.fonts"
        app:fontProviderPackage="com.google.android.gms"
        app:fontProviderQuery="Shantell Sans"
        app:fontProviderCerts="@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs">
</font-family>
```

But when I run my app, it loads the default font instead of Shantell Sans.

If I try other fonts like "Hi Melody" or "Patrick Hand" in fontProviderQuery, the font is loaded correctly.

```
app:fontProviderQuery="Hi Melody"

app:fontProviderQuery="Patrick Hand"
```

According to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/android) all fonts from Google Fonts can be used.

> **Which fonts can I use?**
>
> The entire Google Fonts Open Source collection!
> Visit https://fonts.google.com to browse.

So, why is "Shantell Sans" not loading?

Comment: Do you have the certificate configured? [Adding Certificate](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/text-and-emoji/downloadable-fonts#adding-certificates)

Comment: Yes, I have the certificate configured for Google Fonts. Other fonts are loading